# Openstack - Restrict user access to Regions Or Zones

Tags: openstack, restrictions, openstack-keystone

We are going to upgrade our OpenStack by adding a bunch of new compute nodes. These nodes sole purpose is to host 'tiny' instances for users to run some small-scale experiments or to test stuff. Those server specification just exceed the minimum requirements.

We want for some users to have only access to the 'fast cloud' and some to the 'slow one', is that possible?

We are considering to use either Regions or Zones (preferably) to 'separate' our cloud. We are searching if we can implement these restrictions through keystone. An alternative is to create host aggregates on which only some specific 'slow' or 'fast' flavors can run and then to assign these flavors to specific projects. According to the membership of each project the user will run her VMs in the 'fast' or the 'slow' cloud.